# Using GitHub API from Indy in Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, ssl, github, indy

I'm working on a project in Delphi 10.1 Berlin which integrates with GitHub. This project intends to download repositories via ZIP files. However, I'm facing some issues.

Originally, I chose (as always) to use Indy to integrate with the GitHub API. I've always used Indy for all web API consumption. However, I'm not having any success using it with GitHub.

The API requires HTTPS. I have obtained the latest OpenSSL DLLs for use with Indy, and am using the Indy library with Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

I have setup a `TIdHTTP` component with a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` attached. I've set that IO Handler to all the `Method` options available, and not one gives me a valid response. I get one of two different responses...

1. When using `sslvSSLv3`, I get: `error:14094410:SSL routines: SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.`
2. When using `sslvTLSv1_2`, I get: `error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

I had to resort to `TRESTClient` for now just to be able to work with the API. But it doesn't handle binary properly.

The test is as simple as `https://api.github.com`. I can call that in Chrome and Postman, and get a response. Just not via Indy.

How can I accomplish a connection with GitHub's API via Delphi's Indy library?

Comment: You should use the IOHandler's `SSLVersions` property instead of its `Method` property. Try setting the `SSLVersions` to `[sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Indy HTTP subclass works with the GitHub API.

```
type
  TIndyHttpTransport = class(TIdCustomHTTP)
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

uses
  IdSSLOpenSSL;

{ TIndyHttpTransport }

constructor TIndyHttpTransport.Create;
var
  SSLIO: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  inherited Create;

  HTTPOptions := HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];

  SSLIO := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  SSLIO.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
  SSLIO.SSLOptions.Mode        := sslmClient;
  SSLIO.SSLOptions.VerifyMode  := [];
  SSLIO.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

  Self.IOHandler := SSLIO;

  // Request.UserAgent := 'my useragent string';

end;
```

Maybe your code also needs to modify the user agent string (because I use this code with different service providers, not only GitHub. Some of them require a modified user agent string instead of the default).

Source: https://github.com/michaelJustin/daraja-framework/blob/master/demo/common/IndyHttpTransport.pas

Comment: Thanks, it was a combination of selecting all 3 TLS versions and the user agent.

Comment: To clarify, `[sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]` solved my immediate problem, but then I had a new problem which was then solved by changing the user agent string. Without changing that, I was getting an error page (HTML) telling me that my access to the site has been restricted (which had me scared at first that I killed my access token by too many failed attempts).